# Why is the @Test annotation necessary? (Java JUnit)

Tags: java, unit-testing, annotations

I was wondering why it is necessary to put @Test above your test methods and what its use is.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's necessary for JUnit to test. Please see [JUnit Cookbook](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/cookbook/cookbook.htm)

Comment: It tells JUnit which methods are unit tests to be executed in the test harness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to run your unit tests, you have to tell JUnit what the tests are. Usually, you have a lot of tests, so individually listing classes/methods in a configuration file somewhere would become a major headache.

So what the framework does instead is scan all your code for classes that look like tests (using reflection). The old way was to have a defined super-class `extends Test` and methods following a naming pattern. Now that we have annotations, you use the `@Test` annotation for that.